# MYSQLi query error in a form

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to find the error. This form is supposed to update a category in the database.

When I try to update the category it gives me this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: cat_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\CMS_project\admin\categories.php on line 90
>   QUERY FAILED!You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

This is the code below, i've commented where is the line 90.

```html
                   <form action="categories.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                   <label for="cat_title">Update Category</label>

                                       <?php
                                            if(isset($_GET['edit']))
                                               {
                                                $cat_id = $_GET['edit'];
                                                $query = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
                                                $select_categories_id = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

                                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories_id))
                                                {
                                                 $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
                                                 $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
                                        ?>
                                    <input value="<?php if(isset($cat_title)){echo $cat_title;} ?>" type="text" name="cat_title" class="form-control">  


                                        <?php } } ?>

                                        <?php
                                        if(isset($_POST['update_category']))
                                        {
                                         $the_cat_title = $_POST['cat_title'];

                                            //Below is line 90

                                            $query = "UPDATE categories SET cat_title = '{$the_cat_title}' WHERE cat_id = {$cat_id} ";
                                            $update_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                                                if(!$update_query)
                                                {
                                                 die("QUERY FAILED!" . mysqli_error($connection));   
                                                }
                                        }
                                        ?> 

                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="submit" name="update_category" value="Update Category" class="btn btn-primary">
                                </div>

                            </form>
```

This is where the form gets the ID

```
    <?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_categories))
{
 $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
 $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
 echo "<tr>
       <td>{$cat_id}</td>
       <td>{$cat_title}</td>
       <td><a href='categories.php?delete={$cat_id}'>Delete</a></td>
       <td><a href='categories.php?edit={$cat_id}'>Edit</a></td>
      </tr>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put column names between backticks ` ` because you could prevent an error which is caused by mysql reserved words

Comment: in the second `if` you actually didn't define `$cat_id` ...

Answer (score 0):

The $cat_id variable is simply not defined in the scope of your query. This means, that the $cat_id variable is only declared inside if statement where you check if $_GET['edit'] is set.
To fix it, add a hidden field with category id to your form, and then in PHP add:

```
$cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
```

just before the 90th line.

By the way remember to use mysqli_real_escape_string to prevent SQL-incjection issues.

Comment: I edited the OP and added where the form gets the ID.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I had to delete the categories.php from the action in form, if I leave it blank it works fine. :)